# Oracle Apex delete entry from collection

Tags: checkbox, collections, oracle-apex

I have two interactive reports with check boxes. If the user select entries from interactive report1 and press a button, the selected entries will be added into a collection and displayed in interactive report2.

In interactive report2 I have again a checkbox and if the user select an entry, it should be deleted from the collection and interactive report2 by pressing a button.

I have defined a process which is fired when the button is pressed:

```
declare v_id number;
begin
FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03.count

LOOP
select id into v_id from apex_collections where collection_name = 'SELECTED2' and c001 = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(i);
   apex_collection.delete_member(
   p_collection_name => 'SELECTED2',
   p_seq => v_id);
END LOOP;
end;
```

SELECTED2 is the name of the collection.

APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03 is the checkox value of the check box in interactive report2.

Problem, the entire collection is deleted and not only the selected rows in  interactive report2. How could I delete only the selected rows?

Comment: That code doesn't delete the collection. Are you 100% the collections isn't deleted in another place during processing ? Another thing to check is that you're using a different id for ```APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX``` in both reports. Else it will take the values from both reports in the page process.

Comment: Also notice there is no ```id``` column in ```apex_collections```. You want ```seq_id```

Comment: Could you please explain why it's not deleting? As far as I understand, line 3-4 lopp over the collection and apex_collection.delete_member delet the entry?

Comment: What do you mean with seq_id, v_id?

Comment: The select ```select id into v_id from apex_collections```. There is no "id" column in apex_collections. You need ```SELECT seq_id INTO v_id FROM apex_collections``` - check the documentation. That could be why it doesn't delete. This has nothing to do with the entire collection being deleted, that must happen somewhere else  - not in this pl/sql block.

Comment: So seq_id is combination from p_seq & v_id?

Comment: Combination ? No. p_seq refers to the column seq_id in apex_collections. When I try ```select id from apex_collections``` I get the error ```ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier```. There is no "id" column in apex_collections. This API is very well documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI753

Comment: But p_seq refers to "p_seq => v_id" in above example

Comment: Check my answer. It has a working example on emp/dept sample data scheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example on the emp/dept schema with 2 interactive reports:

- IR_1 on emp with all records that are in table but not in collection
- IR_2 on emp with all records that are in collection

When a user selects checkbox in IR_1 and submits, those records are put in a collection. When a user selects checkbox in IR_2 and submits, record is removed from collection.

IR_1 has query:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,empno,'UNCHECKED') AS CHECKBOX
  from EMP
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT n001 FROM apex_collections WHERE collection_name = 'EMP' AND n001 = empno)
```

and a button "ADD" with action "Submit Page" in IR_1 region

IR_2 has query:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(2,empno,'UNCHECKED') AS CHECKBOX
  from EMP WHERE empno IN (SELECT n001 FROM apex_collections WHERE collection_name = 'EMP')
```

and a button "REMOVE" with action "Submit Page" in IR_2 region.

Create 2 page processes of type Execute Code:

1. "Add to Collection"

```
IF NOT APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS ( p_collection_name => 'EMP') THEN
  APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION( p_collection_name => 'EMP');
END IF;
FOR I in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
  APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER (
    p_collection_name => 'EMP',
    p_n001 => to_number(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i)));
END LOOP;
```

Condition: When button pressed = ADD

2. "Remove fromCollection"

```
FOR I in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02.COUNT LOOP
  FOR j IN (SELECT seq_id FROM apex_collections WHERE collection_name = 'EMP' and n001 = to_number(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(i)))
  LOOP
    APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_MEMBER (
      p_collection_name => 'EMP',
      p_seq => j.seq_id);
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

Condition: When button pressed = REMOVE

*Note:* Since those 2 interactive reports are on a single page 2 different ids need to be taken for the checkbox. IR_1 uses 1 (and  `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01`) in the page process and IR_2 uses 2 - (and  `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02`) in the page process.

Comment: Ok, I implemented your example and now I got it (finally, sorry). Very helpful thank you very much!