# Oracle Apex 20.2 (IR): How I can get selected row(s) and process its data through a function

Tags: select, oracle-apex, interactive

please somebody guide how to process selected row(s) from Interactive Report to execute a function one-by-one which return success/failure result (like update select employee's information etc.)

Comment: What do you mean by "one-by-one which return success/failure result" ? If a user selects an employee and clicks the button. What is supposed to happen in case of success and in case of failure (in in combined case - some pass/some fail) ?

Comment: thanks @KoenLostrie loop though all selected rows and process one-by-one calling function for each and will insert employee # and name in case of failure and continue to process next selected employee in IR. hope it cleared. regards

Comment: Here are 2 answers I posted on earlier questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484608/how-to-work-with-checkbox-and-how-to-insert-the-records-which-is-checked/69488178#69488178), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280576/oracle-apex-delete-entry-from-collection/). You can probably figure out how to solve your issue by checking out those.

Comment: thanks again @KoenLostrie, will check how these help me. regards